# findViewById in fragment without put in onCreateView

Tags: android, fragment

I want to know it is possible to setup my TextView outside the onCreateView method.

Here is the code successfully run on Android studio

```
public class TabMatchFragmentOdd extends Fragment {
    TextView Home, Away;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_match_odd, container, false);
        Home = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.homename);
        Away = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.awayname);
        getIncomingIntent();

        return v;
    }

    private void getIncomingIntent() {
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("HomeName") && getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("AwayName")) {
            String HomeName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("HomeName").toString();
            String AwayName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("AwayName").toString();
            setContent(HomeName,AwayName);        
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setContent(String home, String away) { 
        Home.setText(home);
        Away.setText(away);
    }
}
```

But I want to make my code more clear by specific method

Can I do in above similar way?

```
public class TabMatchFragmentOdd extends Fragment {
    TextView Home, Away;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v;
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_match_odd, container, false);
        getIncomingIntent();
        return v;

    }

    private void getIncomingIntent() {
        if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("HomeName")&&getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("AwayName")) {
            String HomeName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("HomeName").toString();
            String AwayName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("AwayName").toString();
            setContent(HomeName,AwayName);         
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setContent(String home, String away) {
        Home = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homename);
        Away = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.awayname);      
        Home.setText(home);
        Away.setText(away);
    }
}
```

After I run the app, it gives me a NullPointException

No matter if I use `getActivity()` or `getView()`, it doesn't work.

What is the concept behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First about inflating views:**

This code here:

```
View v;
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_match_odd, container, false);
```

"Inflates" the View which means that it takes xml file and just create all those objects. So after that v is a view that contains all other views defined in your xml. That is why you can use:

```
(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.awayname);
```

Because this TextView is definec inside View.

**getView() and getActivity() difference**

Another thing is that your Fragment is "hosted" by Activity. It also has it's View (inflated by usage of setContentView(...) method). By this you can use Activity.findViewById() and you will be able to find views inflated in Activity's xml file (set in setContentView()).
That is why:

```
(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.awayname);
```

works, and

```
(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.awayname);
```

doesn't. Activity simply hasn't inflated the view containing R.id.awayname.
So as you see: getActivity() returns you just the activity that is "hosting" fragment, and getView() returns the view that you've returned from onCreateView() method.

**Why getView() produces null?**

It's because you've used getView() method before onCreateView() return statement.

**What to do?**

To make it work it's wise to create properties inside of your Fragment/Activity like this:

public class TabMatchFragmentOdd extends Fragment {
TextView Home, Away;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_match_odd, container, false);
    getViews(v);
    return v;
}

private void getIncomingIntent() {
    (...)
    setContent(HomeName,AwayName);         
}

private void getViews(View v) {
    Home = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.homename);
    Away = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.awayname);      
}

private void setContent(String home, String away) {
    Home.setText(home);
    Away.setText(away);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation , i got it !

Answer (score 3):

The `Layout` of your `Fragment` has nothing to do with the `Layout` of your `Activity` hence your `getActivity().findViewById` will fail.

In the `onCreateView` after inflating the `Layout` do the following:

```
Home = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.homename);
```

Some coding style tips: Make your `TextView`'s access `private`. When naming them start with `lowercase` and append `Tv` to the end so you know this `private field` is a `TextView`

Comment: Thank you Rene, now i know the diff between fragment and activity, and your coding tips really helpful

Comment: You're welcome! Well there is more to it ofcourse ;) Just imagine - when inflating a layout - the `View` you get back as the root element and all the Views you get by `findViewById` are "underneath" it. (Note I described it this way so you can imagine it better). Anyway if you have any further questions just ask!

Comment: Thanks again for spending so much time :)  Now i got it

Answer (score 2):

> After i run the app, it have a nullpointexception error
>
> No matter i use getActivity() or getView() it not work.
>
> what is the concept behind that?

When you call `getView()`, you will get the following results:

- If `onCreateView()` hasn't completed yet, `getView()` returns `null`
- If `onCreateView()` has completed, `getView()` returns whatever you returned in `onCreateView()`

In your code, `setContent()` is called by `getIncomingIntent()`, which is called by `onCreateView()`. That means that `onCreateView()` hasn't completed yet, so `getView()` will always return null at this point.

The smallest change you can make to your second snippet of code is to move your `getIncomingIntent()` call out of `onCreateView()` and into `onViewCreated()`:

```
public class TabMatchFragmentOdd extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_match_odd, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        getIncomingIntent();
    }

    private void getIncomingIntent() {
        if (getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("HomeName") && getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra("AwayName")) {
            String HomeName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("HomeName").toString();
            String AwayName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("AwayName").toString();
            setContent(HomeName, AwayName);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No:", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void setContent(String home, String away) {
        TextView Home = getView().findViewById(R.id.homename);
        TextView Away = getView().findViewById(R.id.awayname);
        Home.setText(home);
        Away.setText(away);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, i learnt something new from your OnViewCreated method now,